# React.js: Should parent or component manage state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "Date input" component that contains a `<input type="text">`.

It's purpose is to allow users to type in a valid date (e.g., *mm/dd/yyyy*).

***Once*** a user enters a valid date, the parent of the component should receive that date.

Based on this - I'm trying to figure out whether the component or the parent should manage state.

If I set it up so ***the parent*** manages state:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

... this is no good, because the parent will be notified with every single change, and the prop will be set to all the "draft" values (e.g., "07/2") while the user is typing.

That suggests that I should set this up so that ***the component*** manages it's own state:

```
class InputDateWithLabel extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: formatDate(this.props.value) // formatDate() formats a date object into an 'mm/dd/yyyy' string
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);

    }

    handleChange(event) {
        // use setState() to update this.state.value so the <input> shows what the user types
    }

    handleBlur(event) {
        // if the user entered a valid date,
        // convert the user's input to a date object,
        // and communicate that to the parent. E.g.,:
        this.props.onChange([new date]);
        // Otherwise, handle the "error"
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleBlur} />
        );
    }
}
```

This version works exactly the way I want it to, *except for one more requirement*...

Based on things that might happen elsewhere in my application, the parent ***may*** need to set the date in this component. However - now that the component is managing it's own state - when the parent changes `props.value`, my component will ignore it.

The React documents address this scenario here: [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)

But their solutions don't seem to apply:

> One way to avoid the problems mentioned above is to remove state from our component entirely.

This is no good, because I don't want to make the parent responsible for validating the user's date input. My component should be self-contained, including the date validation, which means it needs to manage the "draft states" of the user's input.

> Another alternative would be for our component to fully own the “draft” state. In that case, our component could still accept a prop for the initial value, but it would ignore subsequent changes to that prop

This is no good, because I need to retain the ability for the parent to change the value ***when appropriate.***

The rest of the React documentation mentions a few other possibilities (`getDerivedStateFromProps`), but it goes to great lengths to stress that ***they're probably not correct.*** (Note the title of the article!)

This does not seem like an uncommon situation, so there must be a clear, simple, well-documented way to handle it, that's done the right "React-way". What is that?

Comment: I think you should choose whether  this component is controlled or uncontrolled. why not make it controlled and invoke an `onChange`  callback when the value passes the valdations?

Comment: Using `<input value={this.state.value}>` is not a good approach. It's a known error-prone.

Comment: @Sagivb.g According to the React docs, "In most cases you should use controlled components". That seems like the "right way" to do it, which is what I'd like to do. So - I'm trying to accomplish my goal using a controlled component, where the component manages it's own state, ***but*** the parent still has the ability to set the value ***when appropriate.*** How do you do *that* with a controlled component?

Comment: **"where the component manages it's own state"** that's the opposite from a controlled component.

Comment: @IsaacFerreira I understand that `<input value={this.state.value}>` is error-prone. But *what is the better way to do it?* I don't want to use `<input value={this.props.value}>`, because that means that the component is sending the parent all the ***draft*** versions of the input (e.g., "07/2"), rather than a valid date object.

Comment: @Sagivb.g The React documentation is confusing. Sometimes "controlled/uncontrolled" is about whether the parent or the component itself manages state. But other times, "controlled/uncontrolled" is about whether you're using React or the DOM to manage state (see this: https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components)

Comment: @mattstuehler Think of the "DOM" as a component, if you pass it a value and an onChange event then it's controlled. it's the same for any component you would write.

Comment: @mattstuehler On one hand you don't want the parent to be "bothered" with the logic of what is a valid input. On the other hand, you do want the parent to be able set a valid input, well it seems that the parent will have to be involved with the logic of a valid input anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Having a component manage it's own state doesn't seem that bad in your case, but you will need to add componentWillReceiveProps which adds another piece of code to manage.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
        value: formatDate(nextProps.value)
    });
}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps`  is [deprecated and should be avoided](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating)

Comment: AH, well I will stop using it myself then.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jason - Thanks for this suggestion. But, the React documentation is pretty clear that you shouldn't do that. `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated, and they describe this as an *anti-pattern*!

Comment: All you want to know about the changes in [this blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

Comment: Yep, I see that now.  Good to know.   This is a good article (which tailed off Sagiv's link) https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key

Comment: There are new methods and alternatives for this but it is considered as an anti pattern because its breaking the single source of truth. You can make it work but it may lead to nasty bugs down the road.